# Hour start and Hour end for an appointment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am looking a way to create a form for an appointment, I have 2 fields so far, in format "string", is it correct according you?

```
<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('hour_start') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="company-content">Hour Start</label>
        <select name="hour_start" id="" class="form-control">
           <option value="">Hour Start</option>
           <option value="08:00" @if (old('hour_start') == "08:00") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>08:00</option>
           <option value="10:00" @if (old('hour_start') == "10:00") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>10:00</option>
        </select>
</fieldset>

 <fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('hour_end') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="company-content">Hour End</label>
        <select name="hour_end" id="hour_end" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Hour End</option>
            <option value="10:00" @if (old('hour_end') == "10:00") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>10:00</option>
            <option value="13:00" @if (old('hour_end') == "13:00") {{ 'selected' }} @endif>13:00</option>
        </select>
</fieldset>
```

I think the validation will be complicated?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure - nothing wrong with a simple string as your DB item and the value for the option.  If it is short, you can even have advantage in future when you want to draw the variable field (It will display the exact text of what you want vs an id).  You wouldn't want to do this with long strings or too many options, but for a time and just a few - seems fine.  Validate old style using an if-check.  With only a few options, this isn't cumbersome.

Comment: if you only allow those 4 values than i guess its a possible solution. But then again, there are only 3 valid combinations.

Comment: @Watercayman: Thanks for your explanations, as usual ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can also just put your options in an array and use foreach,if you need to add other options later on it will simplify it, up to you.

```
$options = ['10:00','13:00'];

@foreach($options as $opt)
<option value="{{$opt}}" @if (old('hour_end') == $opt) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>{{$opt}}</option>
@endforeach
```